# Generic method containing URL Session data task doesn't execute

Tags: swift

I have a problem I can't wrap my head around.  For some reason, my URLSession data task doesn't seem to be executing at all.  Any ideas why?

Here's the network manager class:

```
class RBCConsentsNetworkManager {
    static let shared = RBCConsentsNetworkManager()
    
    func fetchGenericJSONData<T: Decodable>(url: URL, completion: @escaping ([T]?, Error?) -> ()) {
        
        print(" fetchGenericJSONData -> T is type: \(T.self); url: \(url)")
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, resp, err) in
            print(" fetchGenericJSONData -> in completion")
            if let err = err {
                print(" fetchGenericJSONData -> ERROR")
                completion(nil, err)
            }
            print(" json: \(data?.prettyPrintedJSONString!)")
            do {
                let objects = try JSONDecoder().decode([T].self, from: data!)
                print(" fetchGenericJSONData -> WORKED")
                completion(objects, nil)
            } catch {
                print(" fetchGenericJSONData -> ERROR")
                completion(nil, error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
    func fetchConsents(completion: @escaping fetchConsentStatusCompletionWithData) {
        print(" RBCConsentsService -> fetchConsents")
        guard let consentFeatureDetailsURL = fetchByFeatureCodeURL, let consentUserDetailsURL = fetchByUserURL else { 
            print(" RBCConsentsService -> fetchConsents -> bailing out -> unable to unwrap URLs -> ")
            completion(.failure(ConsentServiceError.invalidURL))
            return 
        }
        print(" RBCConsentsService -> fetchConsents -> consentFeatureDetailsURL: \(consentFeatureDetailsURL)")
        print(" RBCConsentsService -> fetchConsents -> consentUserDetailsURL: \(consentUserDetailsURL)")
        RBCConsentsNetworkManager.shared.fetchGenericJSONData(url: consentFeatureDetailsURL, completion: { (consentsByFeatureCode: [RBCConsentsByFeatureCode]?, err) in 
            print(" RBCConsentsService -> fetchConsents -> inside completion...")
            if let _ = err {
                print(" RBCConsentsService -> fetchConsents -> ERROR")
                completion(.failure(ConsentServiceError.decodeError))
                return
            }
            
            RBCConsentsNetworkManager.shared.fetchGenericJSONData(url: consentUserDetailsURL, completion: { (consentsByUser: [RBCConsentsByUser]?, err) in 
                print(" RBCConsentsService -> fetchConsents -> inside nested 2nd completion...")
                if let _ = err {
                    print(" RBCConsentsService -> fetchConsents -> ERROR")
                    completion(.failure(ConsentServiceError.decodeError))
                    return
                }
                if let consentsFC = consentsByFeatureCode, let consentsUser = consentsByUser {
                    print(" succeeded!")
                    completion(.success((consentsFC, consentsUser)))
                } else {
                    print(" RBCConsentsService -> fetchConsents -> ERROR")
                    completion(.failure(ConsentServiceError.dataError))
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

The last line that executes in the generic fetch json method is:
`print(" fetchGenericJSONData -> T is type: \(T.self); url: \(url)")`

I can't figure out why it's not executing the network request.

Comment: Who calls `func fetchConsents(completion: @escaping fetchConsentStatusCompletionWithData)`? You aren't testing in Playgrounds or a Swift Script, right? It's a "real app"?